# How to make httpd accessible only through the VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, centos, pptp, httpd

I have a server running PPTP that is supposed to run an httpd (nginx) accessible only through the VPN. I'm also running a few other httpds too, which are not supposed to work on the VPN.

routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
x.x.x.x         x.x.x.x         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 bond0
x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 bond0
x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1008   0        0 bond0
```

when I ping mydomain.com (that should work with VPN)

```
ping mydomain.com
PING mydomain.com (x.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- mydomain.com ping statistics ---
32 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 31248ms
```

but I can see the packets in tcpdump -vv -i  ppp0

```
15:21:09.543764 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 37313, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    cable-x.x.x.x.dynamic.provider.com > anon-60-160.vpn.ipredator.se: ICMP echo request, id 4652, seq 8, length 64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could probably configure that particular nginx instance to only listen on the PPTP interface.

[The documentation for the http_core module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) specifies a listen directive to allow nginx to only listen on a certain address and/or port.

`listen <IP of VPN>:<port>` on the instance of nginx that should work on the vpn should be ok

Comment: vpn ip is always changing it's not static. but the problem is I can't even ping to the vpn ip from the internet that's  why I think I should change the nat first, before I start with nginx.

Comment: You can use hostnames too for the listen directive. Also some providers will block pings from reaching their endpoints, so pings aren't an effective diagnostic tool anymore :(

Comment: so I can set `listen ppp0:<port>`?

Comment: Not quite. You could do `listen www.yoursite.com:80`. Hostnames and IP addresses, not interfaces for nginx.

Comment: Tried `listen mydomain.com:80` but it's not workings. though I can see  the requests from `tcpdump -vv -i  ppp0` which is a good sign

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lsof -i | grep http` ?

Comment: no it's a production server.

Comment: Ok then, can you verify that nginx is listening on the right port with lsof ?

Comment: at the beginning `nginx     26178      root   50u  IPv4  87709753      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
` and than many `nginx     26181    apache  256u  IPv4  92480971      0t0  TCP x.x.x.x.colo.static.dc.domain.com:http->x.x.x.x.megaline.domain.com:20863 (ESTABLISHED)
`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do It -- run the server on dedicated port and reject requests from interfaces other then ppp for this port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i ! ppp+ -p tcp --dport <protected-port> -j REJECT
```

The main drawback of the above approach - your server may still become accidentally open.

---

If you are looking for stable and reliable solution for protected special-purpose server staff then I recommend the following way:

Choose any free dedicated private address, say `10.255.255.1`.

Setup internal virtual tap interface using this address.

```
# cat > ifcfg-tap0
DEVICE=tap0
TYPE=Tap
IPADDR=10.255.255.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
```

Optionally disable proxy-arp in `/etc/sysctl.conf` if not needed:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp=0
```

Choose dedicated port to run your http server on, say `8888`.

Bind your server to dedicated ip/port:

```
listen 10.255.255.1:8888
```

Restrict access to 10.255.255.1 (locally or from VPN only):

```
-I INPUT -p ip -s 10.255.255.1 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i ! ppp+ -p ip -d  10.255.255.1 -j REJECT
```

The major work has been done. All applications bound exclusively to 10.255.255.1 are accessible only internally or using VPN.

But now you need to care about routing to 10.255.255.1 on client side. You can avoid It and make your http server accessible trough VPN with any IP address you are generally using to access the host:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p tcp --dport 8888 -d <normal_server_address> -j DNAT --to 10.255.255.1:8888
```